# How to display the current polygon area when editing in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis-3, editing, area

I use **QGIS 3.10** to create new polygons manually.

**I want to see the area of an object interactively during its creation.**

I know that **after** creating a polygon, you can **automatically** calculate its area and display this value in the attribute table, **but this option does not suit me**.

How to do that?

Comment: Does it have to be during the creation, or could it be during editing?

Comment: @Erik During the creation.

Comment: Does the CalcArea plugin do what you need?

Comment: @johns This almost fit my needs, the CalcArea plugin only works with the "Add Polygon" tool. The “Shape Digitization Toolbar” is not supported (creating circles, rectangles, etc.). It would also be nice to choose a CRS to calculate the area. I'm going to report the issue to the creator of this plugin.

Comment: One workaround is to create a "drawing" geopackage that you store "temporary" shape(s) in for any project you are working in.  This would allow you to create shapes using the Calc Area plugin.  Periodically you could go in and clean out this geopackage of your accumulated "drawings".  This isn't as nice as having the drawing shape in memory so it is only a workaround.  I think ArcGIS Pro basically uses this workaround with a default file geodatabase for its "drawings" .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by [@johns](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/7783/johns) the `CalcArea` plugin could be used to solve this problem.

Plugin homepage: https://github.com/klausib/CalcArea/

Answer (score 0):

Plugin "CalcArea2" should do all of this after old CalcArea was depriciated. It looks very promising according to manual on github but unfortunately does not work yet in latest QGIS versions 3.28.7 or 3.30.2 I have. This should be basic QGIS drawing feature, IMO - we had it in ArcView 3.x back in the days.